# How do significant figures work in a cross unit division?

Tags: unit-of-measure, slope, significant-figures

In one of my problems, I needed to find a slope on a graph with different units in physics.

309 cm² - 0.0 cm² / 100 cm - 0.0 cm

The answer is A = 3.09 r² with A being area and r² being radius squared.

My main issue is with the significant figures.

0.0 is the smallest significant digit here. So logically, 0 should be the significant figure, since 0.0 is the smallest. But it is not.

Why is that so?

And what if the 0 was 1.0, would that make the answer A = 3.1 r²?

Thanks

Comment: The units and significant digits are two different things to be concerned about. They don't really affect one another. In this case the $3.09$ looks fine, but the units do not: either the units in the divisor should have been $\text{cm}^2,$ or there is an even more serious error in the setup of this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The point of significant figures is to have an idea how many digits of the final result are actually meaningful to report. For example, you have no business reporting a particular result as $4.52055936$ if you cannot even be reasonably sure that the true value is between $4.51$ and $4.53.$

When you make several operations on numbers to get the final result, you have to keep track of significant digits at each step.
When you take $309 - 0.0,$ the result is just $309$: you don't write it as $309.0,$ because doing so would imply that you know the digit after the decimal point, and the amount of variation that the actual first number might have from the stated value $309$ is too great to specify a digit after the decimal point.
That is, in order for the result of $309 - 0.0$ to have a significant digit after the decimal point, *both* inputs have to have a significant digit after the decimal point.

Likewise with $100 - 0.0$ the result is $100,$ not $100.0.$
This is actually a bit ambiguous; I do not believe there is a universal convention regarding exactly how many of the digits of $100$ are significant.
According to some conventions only the first digit (the $1$) would be significant.
But if your particular convention is that all digits of a number written as an integer are significant, including trailing zeros, then $100$ has three significant digits.

You then divide a number of three significant digits by another number of three significant digits, and we optimistically allow you to keep three significant digits in the result: $309/100 = 3.09.$ (I say this is optimistic because every multiplication or division operation introduces the possibility of a larger percentage variation in the result.)

If you had $1.0$ instead of the first $0.0$ then you would have 
$309 - 1.0 = 308$ and $308/100 = 3.08.$
But if you had $-1.0$ instead of the first $0.0$ then you would have 
$309 - (-1.0) = 310$ and $310/100 = 3.10,$
assuming that all digits written in integer form are significant.

Answer (score 0):

If rounded to one decimal place, $309.0$ has a range from $308.95$ to $309.04$ and $100.0$ a range from $99.95$ to $100.04$. If we just look at the extremes, the division ranges from $3.088$ to $3.092$. So $3.09$ is a meaningful result whereas $3.1$ introduces further rounding error.